# How to convert R script into a function

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown, r-markdown

I wrote a R script to create a PDF (via LaTeX) with R Markdown. The script does what I want it to do but I would like to improve it regarding the DRY principle. Right now I have to repeat myself at some points because the functions I would like to use do not work.

I tried to convert the following script into a function:

This code works as it is (any suggestions to improve it are welcome but this is not the focus of my question):

```r
df$lo_so[grepl("[A-z]", df$lo_so)] <- "0"
df$lo_so[grepl("[.?!-]", df$lo_so)] <- "0"
gsub("\\.", ",", df$lo_so)
newvec <- as.numeric(df$lo_so)
newvec[is.na(newvec)] <- 0
for (i in 1:length(df$lo_so)) {
  if(newvec[i] < 1 & newvec[i] > 0){
    df$lo_so[i] <- as.numeric(df$lo_so[i]) * 100
  }
}
reg <- regexpr("[0123456789]{1,3}", df$lo_so, perl=TRUE)
df$lo_so <- regmatches(df$lo_so, reg)
df$lo_so <- as.numeric(df$lo_so)
df$lo_so <- df$lo_so / 100
```

I need to run this script for several columns in the respective data frame. Therefore, only "df$lo_so" changes, everything else stays the same. So I tried to create the following function:

```r
changeval <- function(z){
  z[grepl("[A-z]", z)] <- "0"
  gsub("\\.", ",", z)
  newvec <- as.numeric(z)
  newvec[is.na(newvec)] <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(z)) {
    if(newvec[i] < 1 & newvec[i] > 0){
      z[i] <- as.numeric(z[i]) * 100
  }
}
  reg <- regexpr("[0123456789]{1,3}", z, perl=TRUE)
  z <- regmatches(z, reg)
  z <- as.numeric(z)
  z <- z / 100
  return(z)
}

changeval(df$lo_hs)
changeval(df$lo_bi)
changeval(df$lo_zu)
changeval(df$lo_un)
changeval(df$lo_so)
```

Unfortunately it does not work but no error message is shown. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the function you just need to call it.

```
changeval(df$lo_so)
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I am sorry, I did not include this part in my question, but I called the function afterwards. Then (as I wrote) no error message is shown but the data frame remains unchanged. It works perfectly fine when the script is used with manually changed values for df$lo_so, just not with the function.

Comment: @mrvideo, are you trying to change a column of a dataframe? If so, are you assigning it like `df$lo_so <- changeval(df$lo_so)` when you call the function?

Comment: @GabrielSilva That's it! Thank you so much. I only ran the function but did not assign the result to the respective columns. This perfectly explains the "no error message, but no changes"-result. Thank you!!!

Comment: @GabrielSilva Sorry to bother you, but I have one follow-up question. I just remembered why I did not assign the function's result to the column in the first place. I thought that when I assign new values to the column **inside** the function like `z <- z / 100` it is already changed afterwards. Why does this not work?

Comment: That is a topic called "envinroment" in R. Your variables (like `df`) are stored in an environment, usually the *Global environment*. However, every function has its own (child) environment. Think of it as an "temporary space" where variables created inside the function (like `z` or `reg`) are stored. When the function exits, its environment and every variable inside it are removed. When you call `f(z = df$x)` you assign `df$x` value to `z`, so `z <- z / 100` changes `z` inside the function but not `df$x`. The function then returns `z` which you need to assign to `df$x` if you want to changeit

Comment: As a matter of fact, a function can change a variable that is outside the its envinroment (thou its not usually advisable) but that is a rather long topic to fit in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said your code works fine but part of why it is hard to convert into a function is because it could be more straight-forward.

Consider your first lines:

```r
df$lo_so[grepl("[A-z]", df$lo_so)] <- "0"
df$lo_so[grepl("[.?!-]", df$lo_so)] <- "0"
gsub("\\.", ",", df$lo_so)
newvec <- as.numeric(df$lo_so)
newvec[is.na(newvec)] <- 0
```

With `dplyr`you could simplify and easily convert to a function, like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

changeval <- function(data,var){
   data %>%
      mutate(var= gsub("[A-z] | [.?!-]","0",var),var = gsub("\\.", ",", var)) %>%
      mutate(var= as.numeric(var), var= case_when(is.na(var) ~ 0, TRUE ~ var)
}

changeval(df,df$lo_so) #this applies the function to the relevant data frame and variable
```

**Edit:**

So a guess on what the other code snippets in your original mean and a translation into `dplyr` logic.

```r
# I assume this loop multiplies any number between 0-1 by 100
for (i in 1:length(df$lo_so)) {
  if(newvec[i] < 1 & newvec[i] > 0){
    df$lo_so[i] <- as.numeric(df$lo_so[i]) * 100
  }
}

# Some more transformations to convert the original value to a pure number by extracting only the numbers via regex and dividing by 100.
reg <- regexpr("[0123456789]{1,3}", df$lo_so, perl=TRUE)
df$lo_so <- regmatches(df$lo_so, reg)
df$lo_so <- as.numeric(df$lo_so)
df$lo_so <- df$lo_so / 100
```

Now my attempt to convert this (if I knew the original data or your intent this could certainly be shorter):

```r
changeval <- function(data,var){
  reg <- regexpr("[0123456789]{1,3}", df$lo_so, perl=TRUE) # This is new
   
  data %>%
      mutate(var= gsub("[A-z] | [.?!-]","0",var),var = gsub("\\.", ",", var)) %>%
      mutate(var= as.numeric(var), var= case_when(is.na(var) ~ 0, TRUE ~ var) %>% # now the new stuff
      mutate(var = as.numeric(regmatches(var,reg))/100)
}

changeval(df,df$lo_so)
```

In general there are multiple transformations I am not sure are necessary. You define a new variable `newvec` for example, I assume it is just a helper variable so I skip it. But maybe you want to have two variables as the output?

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. This looks very good. But if I got it right this does not replace my whole function, right? Actually one thing I struggled with is to separate "df" from "lo_so" to use two variables instead of one. You did this in your code but is this also possible for the second part, e.g. like this?

Comment: ```r
changeval <- function(data,var){
  data %>%
      mutate(var= gsub("[A-z] | [.?!-]","0",var),var = gsub("\\.", ",", var)) %>%
      mutate(var= as.numeric(var), var= case_when(is.na(var) ~ 0, TRUE ~ var)
  for (i in 1:length(data$var)) {
    if(newvec[i] < 1 & newvec[i] > 0){
      data$var[i] <- as.numeric(data$var[i]) * 100
  }
}
  reg <- regexpr("[0123456789]{1,3}", data$var, perl=TRUE)
  data$var <- regmatches(data$var, reg)
  data$var <- as.numeric(data$var)
  data$var <- data$var / 100
  return(data$var)
}
```

Comment: @mrvideo I am using the "piping logic" of `dplyr`. `%>%` basically pushes the left-hand side of the term to the right, so that it does not have to be named explicitly. So `anyfunction(df$lo_so)` becomes `df %>% anyfunction(lo_so)`. I'll try and update my answer if you can provide more info on what the missing functions are supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I tried to understand and copied your code into my script but unfortunately it did not work. First of all there seems to be a missing bracket in your last chunk of code: `mutate(var= as.numeric(var), var= case_when(is.na(var) ~ 0, TRUE ~ var)`. But even with the added bracket I receive the following error message: "Column 'var' must be length 532 (the number of rows) or one, not 372". Do you have an idea to solve that?